# How to sort based on date of custom object in NSArray...?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an Array of custom objects. Say the object is called A and this has a property called timestamp.(This is of NSDate type.)

Now I need to get the objects A filtered in different arrays for (MOnth and Year as unique key).

I have been trying to use predicates but unable to figure out how to put it on date objects.

You can look at the image below to see where exactly I need to use it...

**EDIT**: Removing image.

Comment: very good question i follow your post for the answer...nice attempt :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Code snippet which can help you

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unSortedArray  sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(DateObj *id1, DateObj *id2) {
            if(id1.timeStamp < id2.timeStamp)
                return YES;
            else
                return NO;
        }];
```

Comment: This will just sort it but it will not return the unique combination of (month and year)

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong. 1) You cannot compare NSDate objects with `<`. 2) A comparator must return NSOrderedAscending (-1), NSOrderedSame (0), or NSOrderedDescending (+1), not YES or NO. - The question explicitly states "... timestamp. (This is of NSDate type.)".

Comment: @ShafKhan: Even if timestamp is scalar property so that you can compare with `<`: Returning only YES or NO from a comparator is wrong. Have a look at the documentation of [NSComparisonResult](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult).

Comment: @ShafKhan: *"As NSDate timestamp returns NSTimeInterval"*?? - NSDate does not have a timestamp method.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                  [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:NO]]];
```

Comment: This will just sort it but it will not return the unique combination of (month and year).